# Glue PySpark Job: An error occurred while calling o73.save. ThreadPoolExecutor already shutdown

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue

I have a PySpark glue job which runs in 6 parallel instances for 6 different datasets, in this job I am reading data from s3 using glue_context.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog() and after merging new data writing spark dataframe to s3 again like this

`merged_df.write.mode("overwrite").format("json").partitionBy("year","month","day").save(destination_path)`

this job is running fine for 5 datasets but it fails for one of any some times with error

*An error occurred while calling o73.save. ThreadPoolExecutor already shutdown*

Please help me fixing this.

Comment: What is your input format? Are they compressed? Which operations do you call on the df? Can you pls add more details

Comment: What is your data size and no of dpu configured

Comment: data is in json format and not compressed and is around 11GB, adding few columns deleting few rows on dataframe. using capacity 2.